# Material Ui import gives error "Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory"

Tags: material-ui, next.js

I am building a Next JS app. Everything went well unless I imported **material-ui** to the project.
With material-ui, it is repeatedly giving error:

```
./node_modules/@emotion/styled/dist/styled.browser.esm.js
 Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'D:\ReactProjects\ace\node_modules\@emotion\styled\dist\styled.browser.esm.js'
```

I deleted the material-ui and styled, re-installed but no affect. Anyone knows the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try creating a file named `styled.browser.esm.js` and pasting this into it and placing it into `D:\ReactProjects\ace\node_modules\@emotion\styled\dist\`;

```
import '@babel/runtime/helpers/extends';
import 'react';
import '@emotion/is-prop-valid';
import createStyled from '../base/dist/emotion-styled-base.browser.esm.js';
import '@emotion/react';
import '@emotion/utils';
import '@emotion/serialize';

var tags = ['a', 'abbr', 'address', 'area', 'article', 'aside', 'audio', 'b', 'base', 'bdi', 'bdo', 'big', 'blockquote', 'body', 'br', 'button', 'canvas', 'caption', 'cite', 'code', 'col', 'colgroup', 'data', 'datalist', 'dd', 'del', 'details', 'dfn', 'dialog', 'div', 'dl', 'dt', 'em', 'embed', 'fieldset', 'figcaption', 'figure', 'footer', 'form', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'head', 'header', 'hgroup', 'hr', 'html', 'i', 'iframe', 'img', 'input', 'ins', 'kbd', 'keygen', 'label', 'legend', 'li', 'link', 'main', 'map', 'mark', 'marquee', 'menu', 'menuitem', 'meta', 'meter', 'nav', 'noscript', 'object', 'ol', 'optgroup', 'option', 'output', 'p', 'param', 'picture', 'pre', 'progress', 'q', 'rp', 'rt', 'ruby', 's', 'samp', 'script', 'section', 'select', 'small', 'source', 'span', 'strong', 'style', 'sub', 'summary', 'sup', 'table', 'tbody', 'td', 'textarea', 'tfoot', 'th', 'thead', 'time', 'title', 'tr', 'track', 'u', 'ul', 'var', 'video', 'wbr', // SVG
'circle', 'clipPath', 'defs', 'ellipse', 'foreignObject', 'g', 'image', 'line', 'linearGradient', 'mask', 'path', 'pattern', 'polygon', 'polyline', 'radialGradient', 'rect', 'stop', 'svg', 'text', 'tspan'];

var newStyled = createStyled.bind();
tags.forEach(function (tagName) {
  // $FlowFixMe: we can ignore this because its exposed type is defined by the CreateStyled type
  newStyled[tagName] = newStyled(tagName);
});

export default newStyled;
```

I know this is super weird, but it seems like npm is not putting all the files into the folders.
I resolved an issue like this by taking the file manually from a repo and placing it in my folder.